# How to use Node.js streams to append to end of file?

Tags: node.js, createwritestream

I have a node.js app, which opens a stream:

```
outputStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.txt");
```

I then, asynchronously, add text to the file:

```
outputStream.write( outputTxt, "utf8" );
```

This code is being run inside a loop, so it happens hundreds of times. However, the loop is asynchronous, so it sometimes pauses, and I can edit the `output.txt` file in an external editor in the meantime, and (for example) add a few chars in the beginning.

However, when I do that, the next time the `outputStream.write` is executed, it overwrites the last few chars previously added (the same number of chars that I added externally).

Is there some way to prevent this? Some way to tell the `writeStream` find the end of the file and then add the text?

Comment: I don't know your whole use case, but wouldn't it make sense to append each write to a queue so they're done in order? Completion triggers the callback with processes the next write? You can populate the queue from the loop, but you shouldn't actually write a stream inside of a loop.

Comment: @AltimusPrime I am using promises and recursive functions, not an actual loop.